# Using HQL queries with like clause in jasypt hibernate encryption

Tags: java, hibernate, encryption, hql, jasypt

I am using jasypt hibernate encryptor (with ZeroSaltGenerator) in one of my spring projects.

Everything is working fine but I am stuck at usage of 'like' clause in my HQL queries.

I have a working HQL query like this:

```
List<ConsumerAddress> addressList = sessionFactory.createQuery(
"from ConsumerAddress where city like %:searchString%").setParameter("searchString",request.getSearchString).list();
```

My city field is now encrypted in DB. So above query fails to give any results for search string "beng" even though my DB has entries(encrypted) like "bengaluru" and "bengal". It is obvious because the encrypted string of "beng" need not be a substring of encrypted string of "bengaluru" and "bengal".

**So my question is how can I process such search queries for sensitive  encrypted data?**

I have already well read the documentation at [jasypt site](http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html) mentioning

> But encryption sets a limitation on your Hibernate usage: security
>   standards establish that two different encryption operations on the
>   same data should not return the same value (due to the use of a random
>   salt). Because of this, none of the fields that are set to be
>   encrypted when persisted can be a part of a WHERE clause in your
>   search queries for the entity they belong to.

But this is a very practical scenario where many sensitive fields like consumer address may be encrypted but we may still have to search through them based on given substrings.

**Is there any way I can achieve this?** I have also tried Restrictions.like in hibernate criteria but as expected that also didn't help.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Here is my POJO for reference:

```
//required imports

@TypeDef(name = "encryptedString", typeClass = EncryptedStringType.class, parameters = {
               @Parameter(name = "encryptorRegisteredName", value = "hibernateStringEncryptor") })
@Entity
@Table(name="consumer_address")
public class ConsumerAddress {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="consumer_address_id")
    private Long consumerAddressId;

    @Column(name="address_line_1")
    @Type(type = "encryptedString")
    private String addressLineOne;

    @Column(name="address_line_2")
    @Type(type = "encryptedString")
    private String addressLineTwo;

    @Column(name="city")
    @Type(type = "encryptedString")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="state")
    @Type(type = "encryptedString")
    private String state;

    @Column(name="consumer_user_id")
    private Long consumerUserId;

    //required getters and setters  
}
```

And hibernateStringEncryptor bean is defined as follows in servlet:

```
<bean id="strongEncryptor"
        class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor">
        <property name="algorithm">
            <value>PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${db.encryption.password}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="poolSize">
            <value>${db.encryption.pool.size}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="saltGenerator">
            <bean class="org.jasypt.salt.ZeroSaltGenerator" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateStringEncryptor"
        class="org.jasypt.hibernate4.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor">
        <property name="registeredName"
            value="hibernateStringEncryptor" />
        <property name="encryptor">
            <ref bean="strongEncryptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```